# R (subscript) logical subscript too long

Tags: r

```
library(e1071)
mymodel <- svm(writeoff~.,data=d,kernel="linear",scale = TRUE)
writeoff_pred <- predict(mymodel,c)
```

When I use this code above, I get the error message that tells me:

```
Error in newdata[, object$scaled, drop = FALSE] : 
   (subscript) logical subscript too long
```

how can I solve it?

Comment: How does `dim(c)` compare to `dim(d)`? Are they the same? Do they have identical column names?

Comment: yes they have identical column names. I want to predict them to see yes/no balance. ( Iam beginner in R)

Comment: I think you want to remove your response variable `writeoff` from your `c` object.